ActiveX command button that adds a number of rows based on the value of cell "L5"
I have four command buttons. Each one adds a row to a different table. I would like to be able to add more than one row based on the value of cell "L5". If I click button 1 and the value of "L5" is 10, I want it to add 10 rows to that table, same if I use button 2.
Here is the current code I am using for command button 1:
Sub PV_Field_Add_Row()
  '
  ' PV_Field_Add_Row Macro
  '

  '

    Range("Table15").Select
    Selection.ListObject.ListRows.Add (1)
End Sub


Using For to add more rows on Excel table (ListObject)
Microsoft documentation:

ListRows.Add method (Excel)

Sub PV_Field_Add_Row()
    Dim iVal, Sht As Worksheet
    Set Sht = Worksheets("Sheet1") ' modify as need
    iVal = Sht.Range("L5").Value
    If IsNumeric(iVal) Then
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To iVal
            Sht.ListObjects("Table15").ListRows.Add
        Next
    End If
End Sub


Thanks for @Tim's comment. It's a better solution.
Note: If there isn’t sufficient space (blank rows) below the ListObject, a runtime error will occur. For example, if the ListObject is directly above the PivotTable with only one blank row in between. Insert rows is necessary before resize ListObject.
Microsoft documentation:

ListObject.Resize method (Excel)

Sub PV_Field_Add_Row2()
    Dim iVal, Sht As Worksheet
    Set Sht = Worksheets("Sheet1") ' modify as need
    iVal = Sht.Range("L5").Value
    If IsNumeric(iVal) Then
        With Sht.ListObjects("Table1")
            Dim iCnt As Long
            iCnt = .Range.Rows.Count
            .Range.Rows(iCnt).Offset(1).Resize(iVal).EntireRow.Insert
            .Resize .Range.Resize(iCnt + iVal)
        End With
    End If
End Sub


....or you could use the Resize method: lo.Resize lo.Range.Resize(lo.Range.Rows.Count + iVal) where lo is the listobject

@TimWilliams  Yes, I'll include it in my answer. My initial answer was just based on the original poster's script.

Which line raise the code?

Do I need to set the lo for listobject and add that to the code? I added the lo.Resize lo.Range.Resize(lo.range.rows.count + iVal) portion and I received a run-time '424'error: object required, highlighting  the following : lo.Resize lo.Range.Resize(lo.Range.Rows.Count + iVal).

Doing it as written above gives me a Run-time error '1004': Cannot complete operation: A table cannot overlap with a PivotTable report, query results, a table merged cells, or an XML mapping. Highlighted area: .Resize .Range.Resize(.Range.Rows.Count + iVal)

The error indicates that there isn’t enough space (blank rows) between the ListObject and the PivotTable. In this scenario, you can use the first script in my answer.

I've revised the 2nd script.

Based off of what you mentioned about needing to insert rows, is inserting a row different from adding a row? The original code I posted in my question added rows to the top of the table on a button press. I see that the original code you posted adds a row to the bottom of a table. If they are being added to the top of a table row, would that make a difference with what @TimWilliams wrote?

Thank you both! Each of these works perfectly. Can you explain what the difference between the two above codes is? What makes the Tim's a better solution?

The main difference is in how the scripts expand the Excel table. The first script adds rows one at a time, while the second resizes the table all at once. Generally, the second method is more efficient. However, with a limited number of inserted rows, the user may not notice a difference.
